# c#, build sql to select a user given an age range

Tags: c#, sql

I have a talent table holding all my users with a column holding their birthdays.   what would be the best way Talent within a specified age range.  Here's what I have, but is seems to be off by a couple days.  is there a better way?

```
// BUILD SQL FROM FORM DATA
sqlString += "SELECT * from Talent";

if (minAge != 0 || maxAge != 120)
{
     // The age criteria has been change, filter by age.

     // select all talents that have birthdays between the following 2 dates.
     DateTime startDate = (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan((maxAge * 365), 0, 0, 0));  // maxAge * 365 = totalDays
     DateTime endDate = (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan((minAge * 365), 0, 0, 0));
     sqlString += " WHERE Birthdate BETWEEN '" + startDate.ToString() + "' AND '" + endDate.ToString() + "'";
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but... Use parameterised SQL, *not* string concatenation, to build your query. (Admittedly in this particular case there's no risk of SQL injection, but parameterised SQL is cleaner anyway.)

Comment: Your `(minAge != 0 || maxAge != 120)` clause is bizarre: the only range that's disallowed is 0 to 120. So -1000 to 120 is ok; 0 to 999 is ok; 120 to 0 is ok etc etc.

Comment: @LukeH.  could you provide some example code. Please note that I don't have their age in the database as an int... I only have a dateTime of their birthday, I use this to calculated their age.

Comment: @LukeH.  Yeah I know this is bad: (minAge != 0 || maxAge != 120).  I need to fix it. the default values in the form are 0 to 120.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using SQL Server...

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {

        string tsql = @"
            select *
                from Talent
                where DATEDIFF(YEAR, BirthDay, GETDATE()) BETWEEN @minAge AND @maxAge";

        command.CommandText = tsql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        int minAge = 1;
        int maxAge = 120;

        SqlParameter minAgeParam = command.CreateParameter();
        minAgeParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        minAgeParam.DbType = SqlDbType.TinyInt;
        minAgeParam.ParameterName = "@minAge";
        minAgeParam.Value = minAge;

        SqlParameter maxAgeParam = command.CreateParameter();
        maxAgeParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        maxAgeParam.DbType = SqlDbType.TinyInt;
        maxAgeParam.ParameterName = "@maxAge";
        maxAgeParam.Value = maxAge;

        // Just unsure here whether I must add the parameters to the command,
        // or if they are already part of it since I used the 
        // SqlCommand.CreateParameter() method. 
        // Been too long since I haven't done any ADO.NET
        command.Parameters.Add(minAgeParam);
        command.Parameters.Add(maxAgeParam);

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            // Process your records here...
        } finally {
            connection.Close()
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Dispose();
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Where *@minAge* and *@maxAge* are your age parameters.

You may also tell the [`DATEDIFF` TSQL function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189794.aspx) to consider the difference in days, in month, in hours, in minutes, in seconds, etc. Hence, you will have to convert your parameters value accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the actual birthday, only the year of birth.

Comment: @LukeH: The OP asked for all Talents having an `0 < age < 120`, he actually can do so with the mentioned answer. Nonetheless, the OP can differentiate any date range in any of YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND he wants, all is to tell the `DATEDIFF` function what to differentiate.

Comment: Hi Will, I don't think DATEDIFF will work for me. Say Bobby is born Dec 25 2009, and say the current date is Nov 25 2010. Bobby is not quite 1 yet so he technically is 0 years old if we are just considering years. Because DATEDIFF, in this situation, is just looking at the year part of a date the calculation won't be done correctly. See "datepart Boundaries " here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: @Ray L.: As I said to LukeH, you may take the difference that suits you your need the best. You may also do `DATEDIFF(DAY, Birthday, GETDATE()) BETWEEN @minAge AND @maxAge`, where both *@minAge* and *@maxAge* are expressed as number of days old, considering leap years. Have you visited the link provided in my answer? There you will find what is doable with `DATEDIFF`. I have used this function for about six month in data extraction, so I know it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've found using `startDate.ToString("yy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000")` and `endDate.ToString("yy-MM-dd 23:59:59.000")` works best (note the ,000 on the end date range. For some reason, in my experience, sql is off (probably due to some kind of rounding error) when it comes to ranges.

As an aside, you can use static methods from the `TimeSpan` object for time calculations. e.g. `TimeSpan.FromDays(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to `DateTime.Now`, which considers time as well as date. Try replacing it with a `DateTime.Today`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [DateTime.AddYears](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx) method.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-maxAge);
```

insated of

```
DateTime startDate = (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan((maxAge * 365), 0, 0, 0));
```

Another thing is: Please don't use `+` operator between strings to build a sql query, use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is only marginally less evil than plain string concatenation for building SQL. You should use a parameterised SQL command and avoid string manipulation altogether.

Comment: @LukeK.  Sorry man, string concatenation or the stringBuilder is necessary.   If the user doesn't specify a given age range( ie the values are still 0 and 120) then I don't want the WHERE clause at all.  Validating each record for a would not be necessary.

Comment: @Ray: LukeH is correct. The reason I suggest `StringBuilder` is that I can't give a more detail suggestion here shortly. I think you will see more ORMs in the future, there are quite a lot better solutions than contacting SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - your original solution is off by a few days because it is using 365 instead of accounting for leap years.